# Upgrading from net46 to net461 breaks NuGet package reference

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, nuget, nuget-package

I have a project targeting net46, that references a NuGet package.  This works fine.

This package references a .dll (Package.Reference) that is included in its lib folder.

When the project moves to target net461, this reference no longer works.  The package is still obtained, but it gives error NU1101 on Package.Reference.  Why does a minor version change impact how a package is being loaded, and how can this be fixed?

The [package in question](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HarmonyAnalyzers), in case it's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There might be something wrong with this package
It lists **.NET Standard 2.0** as dependency, which require **.NET Core of minimum** **4.6.1**

But when You look at .NET Core target framework for HarmonyAnalyzers.Interface it says, it's **.NET Core 4.0**

I'd recommend downloading the source code, changing target frameworks yourself and referencing it in your project.